# Sort in Elastic Search take top N records, sort again

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort all documents by field A take top N records, then sort all records again by field B in ElasticSearch?

What I have tried so far is below but it didn't sort by fieldB

```
{  
    "query":{  
     "bool":{  
     "must":[  
        {  
           "match_all":{  

           }
        }
     ],
     "must_not":[  

     ],
     "should":[  

     ]
  }
},
"from":0,
"size":20,
"sort":[  
{
  "FieldA": {
    "missing": "_last",
    "order": "desc"
  }
}, 
{
  "FieldB": {
    "missing": "_last",
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
],
 "aggs":{  

 }
}
```

The equivalent SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 250 FROM TABLE ORDER BY FieldA) ORDER BY FieldB
```

Running on Elasticsearch 5.3

Comment: looks like the search is good and the sort should work as expected. can you give an example of a not-sorted response?

Comment: Above query sorts documents on FieldA first, if there's multiple records for the same value, it'll sort on FieldB second. I want to basically have something like SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 250 FROM TABLE ORDER BY FieldA) ORDER BY FieldB, so the second FieldB is a complete reorder.

Comment: So if I get this right, the only reason for initially sorting by FieldA is to select a subset of the data. The final results from that subset should ultimately be sorted by FieldB, am I correct?

Comment: Also what are the typical values for `FieldA` and `FieldB`?

Comment: correct, the second sort is based on the result of the first sort. FieldA is integer and FieldB is float.

Comment: try this URL  ElasticURL:9200/indexName/_search?sort=FieldA:desc&sort=FieldB  Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968893/elasticsearch-how-to-search-sort-limit-the-results-then-sort-again).

Basically we want to sort the table wrt one column, get the top N results and then sort again wrt another column. The query will also look similar to this.

We will first sort according to fieldA, take the top 50 and then pass this to be sorted by fieldB.

```
{
   "sort":[
      {
         "FieldA": {
           "missing": "_last",
           "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   "size":50,
   "aggs":{
      "top_fieldB_hits":{
         "top_hits":{
            "sort":[
               {
                  "FieldB": {
                    "missing": "_last",
                    "order": "desc"
                   }
               }
            ],
            "size":50
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `top_hits` aggregation is executed over all documents, not only the first 50 ones sorted by `FieldA`